# What is the equalivient to css transition effect, on html items whose css properties are not actually changing?

Tags: html, css

I have a bit of html/php that looks like this:

```
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-25"><label>Email:</label></div>
    <div class="col-75"><input type="text" id="emailAddress" name="emailAddress" onblur="blurHandler(this)" value="<?=$res[0]['emailAddress']?>" required><span
id="marker_emailAddress"></span><br><span class="notice" id="reply_emailAddress">&nbsp;</span></div>
   </div>
```

The idea is that when someone puts focus on the input, enters text (or doesn't) then takes focus off the input, it sends whatever is in the input over fetch api to the server to be processed by php. A response is sent back and fills the two `<spans>`. This all works perfectly, however the arrival of the response from the server pops onto the page suddenly, which is not exactly elegant to the user.

I'd like to get the screen output that displays the servers response, to show it by delivering it via the css effect of `transition-property: ease-in-out;` `transition-duration: 0.5s;`. However I cannot get this to work by any means and from what I have read this seems to be because there is actually no css changes to apply the transition effect to.

Is there some sort of way I can create this effect either by css or something else, to deliver the output onscreen in a more aesthetic manner?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done a reference implementation that demonstrates the idea.
The idea is to give your `span` a class when you load data that changes an animatable property, like `opacity` and then once the data arrives, you remove that class to go back to normal.

```js
const span = document.querySelector('.results');
const button = document.querySelector('.run');
const wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  span.classList.toggle('loading');
  wait(1*1000).then(() => {
    span.innerHTML = Math.random();
    span.classList.toggle('loading');
  })
})
```

```css
.results {
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}
.results.loading {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
<div class="results">
  Data will arrive here with a fade in and fade out effect
</div>
<button class="run">Fetch Data</button>
```

If you prefer fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/ah6xy08j/1/